# C++ - Read char while skipping even lines from file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this in my file and I wanted to **read only the char** and store them in array *rankF[26]*. My problem is **skipping the even lines** while reading the file. Any help would be great. Thanks!

[image]

This is my current code (without skipping lines):

```
int a=0;
if (inputFile){
    while(inputFile >> alpha){
        rankF[a] = alpha;
        a++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string and read the even line in them.

```
string noUse;
int a=0;
if (inputFile){
    while(inputFile >> alpha){
        rankF[a] = alpha;
        a++;
        inputFile >> noUse;//This will read even lines input.
    }
```